# How to convert linkedlist to array using `toArray()`?

Tags: java

I do not know how to convert a linked list of doubles to array. Please help me find the error.

```
import java.util.*;
public class StackCalculator {


  private   LinkedList<Double> values;
  double value1 , value2 ;

  public StackCalculator()
  {
     values = new LinkedList<Double>();
  }


    void push(double x)
    {
         values.addFirst(x);
    }
    double pop()
    {
       return values.removeFirst();
    }
    double add()
    {
        value1=pop();
        value2=pop();
        return (value1 + value2);
    }

    double mult()
    {
        value1=pop();
        value2=pop();
        return (value1 * value2);
    }


    double[] v = new double[10];
    double[] getValues()
    {
        return   values.toArray(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you .That helped me resolve the problem

Answer (score 28):

The `List#toArray()` of a `List<Double>` returns `Double[]`. The `Double[]` isn't the same as `double[]`. As arrays are objects, not primitives, the [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) rules doesn't and can't apply here.

Either use `Double[]` instead:

```
Double[] array = list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);
```

...or create `double[]` yourself using a simple `for` loop:

```
double[] array = new double[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    array[i] = list.get(i); // Watch out for NullPointerExceptions!
}
```

Comment: ow, O(n^2) for loop? why not `int i = 0; for (Double v : list) array[i++] = v;`

Comment: Yeah that second option is pretty terrible. Sparkleshy's suggestion would be much better.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the type of your list, which is `Double` (object), while you're trying to return an array of type `double` (primitive type). Your code should compile if you change `getValues()` to return a `Double[]`.

For your other methods, it's not a problem, because Java automatically converts `Double`s to `double`s and back (called autoboxing). It cannot do that for array types.

Answer (score 1):

`toArray` is defined to return `T[]` where T is a generic argument (the one-argument version is anyway). Since primitives can't be used as generic arguments, toArray can't return `double[]`.