# How to cast JSONArray to int array?

Tags: java, json

I'm having problems with the method `JSONObject sayJSONHello()`.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class SimplyHello {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

     public JSONObject sayJSONHello() {      

        JSONArray numbers = new JSONArray();

        numbers.put(1);
        numbers.put(2);
        numbers.put(3);
        numbers.put(4);             

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        try {
            result.put("numbers", numbers);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

In the client side, I want to get an `int` array, `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, instead of the JSON

```
{"numbers":[1,2,3,4]}
```

How can I do that?

Client code:

```
System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
```

My method returns a `JSONObject`, but I want to extract the numbers from it, in order to perform calculations with these (e.g as an `int[]`).

---

I reveive function as a JSONObject.

```
 String y = service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);   
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(y);   
int [] id = new int[50];
 id = (int [] ) jobj.optJSONObject("numbers:");
```

And then i get error: Cannot cast from JSONObject to int[]

2 other way

```
String y = service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);   
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(y);  
int [] id = new int[50];      
 id = (int [] ) obj.optJSONArray(0);
```

And this time i get: Cannot cast from JSONArray to int[]...

It doesn't work anyway..

Comment: You can parse the json on the client side and get the number from the JSONArray right? How difficult would that be?

Comment: As @benzonico said, you can just access the JSON object's "numbers" element and gain access to the array

Comment: Do you really think what you expect is different from what it is returning?

If yes, then please type in the JSON object you are expecting :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've never used this, nor have I tested it, but looking at your code and the documentation for [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html), this is what I suggest.

```
// Receive JSON from server and parse it.
String jsonString = service.path("rest").path("hello")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

// Retrieve number array from JSON object.
JSONArray array = obj.optJSONArray("numbers");

// Deal with the case of a non-array value.
if (array == null) { /*...*/ }

// Create an int array to accomodate the numbers.
int[] numbers = new int[array.length()];

// Extract numbers from JSON array.
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
    numbers[i] = array.optInt(i);
}
```

This should work for your case. On a more serious application, you may want to check if the values are indeed integers, as `optInt` returns `0` when the value does not exist, or isn't an integer.

> Get the optional int value associated with an index. Zero is returned if there is no value for the index, or if the value is not a number and cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: By the way, is any way to send numbers noit using  numbers.put(1); .. ? e.g in loop ? will send 500 numbers..

Comment: @volly Do not forget to accept an answer, if any solved your problem. There sure are a number of ways not to write every single number. E.g.: `for (int i = 1; i <= 500; ++i) { numbers.put(i); }` puts the numbers from 1 to 500, inclusive, in the array. If you already have the numbers in another array, the code to copy from the regular array to the JSON array is similar to this. E.g.: `int[] myNumbers; /*...*/ for (int i = 0; i < myNumbers.length; ++i) { numbers.put(myNumbers[i]); }`

Answer (score 3):

If you can accept a List as a result, and also can accept using Gson, there is a pretty easy way of doing this, in just a few lines of code:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<LinkedList<Integer>>() {}.getType();
List<Integer> numbers = new Gson().fromJson(jobj.get("numbers"), listType);
```

I realize this is not exactly what you are asking for, but in my experience, a list of integers can be used in many of the same ways as a basic int[]. Further info on how to convert a linkedlist to an array, can be found here: [How to convert linkedlist to array using `toArray()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304242/how-to-convert-linkedlist-to-array-using-toarray)

Answer (score 1):

**May, 2023**

**Java :**

Here is a simple **method** that handles `JSONArray` converting to `Int Array` :

```
public static int[] JSonArray2IntArray(JSONArray jsonArray){
    int[] intArray = new int[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; ++i) {
        intArray[i] = jsonArray.optInt(i);
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

**Kotlin :**

```
val intArr = Array(jsonArr.length()) {jsonArr.getInt(it)}
```

- `intArr` is an `Array<Int>`
- `it` The High-order function is called for each array element sequentially starting from the first one. It should return the value for an array element given its index.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this

```
JSONArray numberArr=jsonObject.getJSONArray("numbers");

            int[] arr=new int[numberArr.length()];
            for(int k=0;k<numberArr.length();k++)
                 arr[k]=numberArr.getInt(k);
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of -

```
result.put("numbers", numbers);
```

you can try (I haven't tested this though)

```
result.put(numbers);
```

Or iterate through the array "numbers" and put each one individually into the "result".

Comment: `JSONObject` likely has no method `put(JSONArray)`.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, there is no `put` method signature with only one parameter. It must have a key.