# Integer array get converted as a string when added as json parameter

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I want to add integer array as a request param in json .I am adding it by using the method.

```
org.json.JSONObject jsonObject=new org.json.JSONObject();
jsonObject.accumulate("",integerArray);
```

but when i am adding it as a param it get converted as string,so not able to parse on server side.
Android-Client side.
Java -Server side.

Comment: Also post the integerArray.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068852/how-to-cast-jsonarray-to-int-array) will help

Comment: ArrayList<Integer>integerArray=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  integerArray.add(2);
  integerArray.add(3);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JSON expert, but have you converted it back to a `JSONArray` on the server side?

```
JSONArray array = jsonObject.optJSONArray("myArray");
```

To make this work you have to call `sonObject.accumulate("myArray",integerArray);` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
org.json.JSONObject jsonObject=new org.json.JSONObject();
jsonObject.accumulate("",new org.json.JSONArray(integerArray));
```

on the client side.

Comment: I have already tried this solution but it is giving me the same result.

Comment: What is the actual output of `jsonObject.toString()` and how do you parse it on the server side?