# convert a linkedlist to an typed array

Tags: java

This should be a relatively straightforward question. But I've got this code where I want to convert a linked list to a typed array. I think it should work, but it's not compiling because of a class cast problem.

The method signature of `setSelectedOptions` takes  `Long[] arg1` but compiler is complaining because the `list.toArray()` signature returns `Object[]`.

I checked this other question: [How to convert linkedlist to array using `toArray()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304242/how-to-convert-linkedlist-to-array-using-toarray) - and it indicates that toArray should be returning a typed list.

Can anyone advise why it's not working? (note I tried to cast the array parameter explicitly to Long[] and got a class cast exception)

```
if (selectedOptions == null)
{
    // set up the carrier delivery options transient option.
    List<Long> list = new LinkedList<Long>();
    for (CarrierDeliveryMethodOptionValue cdv: carrierOptionValues)
    {
        list.add(cdv.getId());
    }

    setSelectedOptions(list.toArray());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `list.toArray(new Long[0]);`.

or, for a *very slight* efficiency gain (only one array is allocated instead of two), use `list.toArray(new Long[list.size()])`.

Comment: Don't know who answered first, both were 2 minutes ago. But this works, thanks. Oh I can't accept it for 10 minutes...

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're using the wrong overload of `toArray`. You want [the one accepting an array `T[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-), which is declared to return a `T[]` as well. It uses the execution-time type of the array to work out the type of array to create - it can't do this without that extra information, because the `LinkedList` itself doesn't "know" its element type. (That's type erasure.)

You can pass an array of *any* length to it - it will create a new one if necessary - so this works:

```
setSelectedOptions(list.toArray(new Long[0]));
```

But for efficiency, you may want to pass one which is the right size already:

```
setSelectedOptions(list.toArray(new Long[list.size()]));
```

As ever with performance, you'll need to balance efficiency with readability depending on how much readability impact you think there is in calling `size()` vs how important the performance is in your context.

Note that if your `setSelectedOptions` method *actually* takes a `long[]` instead of a `Long[]`, you'll need to convert the array separately - auto-unboxing only works for individual items, not whole arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Per the respective JavaDoc(s) calling [`List.toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) returns `Object[]`, that's why there is [`List.toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29)...

**tl;dr**

Change

```
setSelectedOptions(list.toArray());
```

to

```
setSelectedOptions(list.toArray(new Long[0]));
```